# Bulk item Insert/update in SharePoint list using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, sharepoint-rest-api, spservices, bulk

I want to add items in bulk (around 13000 entries) into the SharePoint list using the JavaScript. For this I have already user CSOM Client Context Batch insert code and also I tried the SP.Services() for bulk entries. To complete the entire process, it takes average 13/14 minutes and that is too much. I want to speed up the process, is there any other way that I can achieve this faster.

FYI :- this is not the 1 time process, this can be multiple times.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online (and on-premises SharePoint 2016 and later) and the Office 365 APIs implement the OData $batch query option, you can use it to improve the performance of your add-in by combining many operations into a single request to the server and a single response back.

The following articles for your reference:

[Make batch requests with the REST APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis)

[sp-o365-rest](https://github.com/andrewconnell/sp-o365-rest/blob/master/SpRestBatchSample/Scripts/App.js)

Comment: I tried the above link and try to execute the code, but there is no difference in time.

Comment: could you provide your entire code?